# c++: Access to private variables in abstract base class

Tags: c++, abstract-class, private-members, traveling-salesman

long-time lurker, first-time asker. I'm doing a project on the TSP (Traveling Salesman Problem) in c++ and I have a small question. I need to take two nodes (called NodeIDs in this scenario, they are unsigned ints) and add an edge between them in the addEdge method. The signature along with some notes from my teacher (I will fill in the preconditions later):

```
/* 
 * Add a weighted, undirected edge between nodes u and v.
 * 
 * Preconditions: 
 *     u and v are legal labels (i.e. 0 <= u < G.size(), 0 <= v < G.size())
 *     u != v
 *     There is no edge between u and v.
 *     weight > 0
 */
void ListGraph::addEdge(NodeID u, NodeID v, EdgeWeight weight) {

    /* Code here */

}
```

Now, the way I see myself coding this is referencing the list of edges and nodes in the base class. However, the base class is abstract, and the list is private. Here is the entirety of that base class.
NOTE: THIS CLASS MUST STAY AS IS (it's the teacher's class and one of the few in the project I must remain faithful to and use without changing it.)
Here it is:

```
#include <vector>
#include "Graph.h"

#pragma once

typedef std::list<NWPair> EList;

class ListGraph : public Graph {
public:
    ListGraph(int numNodes);
    ~ListGraph();

    // Modifiers
    virtual void addEdge(NodeID u, NodeID v, EdgeWeight weight);

    // Inspectors
    virtual EdgeWeight weight(NodeID u, NodeID v) const;
    virtual std::list<NWPair> getAdj(NodeID u) const;
    virtual unsigned degree(NodeID u) const;
    virtual unsigned size() const;
    virtual unsigned numEdges() const;

private:
    ListGraph() {;}

    std::vector<EList> edgeList;
    int num_edges;
};
```

The only way I can think to add a weight to the edge between nodes is to access this edgeList and change it. Any suggestions would be quite helpful.

Here is all of Graph.h if anyone needs it:

```
#include <utility>
#include <list>

#pragma once

 /*
 * Useful typedefs, primarily for the purpose of read-ability.
 */
typedef unsigned NodeID;
typedef double EdgeWeight;
typedef std::pair<NodeID, EdgeWeight> NWPair;


class Graph {
 public:
  virtual ~Graph() {}

  /*
   * Add a weighted, undirected edge between nodes u and v.
   * 
   * Preconditions: 
   *     u and v are legal labels (i.e. 0 <= u < G.size(), 0 <= v < G.size())
   *     u != v
   *     There is no edge between u and v.
   *     weight > 0
   */
  virtual void addEdge(NodeID u, NodeID v, EdgeWeight weight) = 0;


  /*
   * Get the weight between nodes u and v; return 0 if there is no edge.
   *
   * Preconditions: 
   *     u and v are legal labels (i.e. 0 <= u < G.size(), 0 <= v < G.size())
   */
  virtual EdgeWeight weight(NodeID u, NodeID v) const = 0;

  /*
   * Return a list of NodeID/EdgeWeight pairs describing the nodes adjacent to edge w.
   *
   * Preconditions: u is a legal label.
   */
  virtual std::list<NWPair> getAdj(NodeID u) const = 0;

  /*
   * Return the degree (i.e. the number of neighorbs) of node u.
   *
   * Preconditions: u is a legal label;
   */
  virtual unsigned degree(NodeID u) const = 0;

  /*
   * Return the number of nodes in the graph.
   */
  virtual unsigned size() const = 0;

  /* 
   * Return the number of edges in the graph.
   */
  virtual unsigned numEdges() const = 0;
};
```

As I said, ANY help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

edit: trying to reference edgeList with "ListGraph::edgeList" in the method "ListGraph::addEdge" results in an error. When I hold my cursor over, it says this:
Error: class "ListGraph" has no member "edgeList"

edit 2: this code is in three files.
Graph.h: unchangeable, abstract; where all methods are
ListGraph.h: unchangeable, mostly abstract; where edgeList and num_edges are (these are private)
ListGraph.cpp: where I will put my code, and seemingly where I cannot access private variables such as edgeList and num_edges

edit 3: I'M AN IDIOT, I put all of the methods in ListGraph.cpp in a class called ListGraph, so the program was searching ListGraph.cpp rather than ListGraph.h. Sorry, wasted yo time, go ahead and delete this if you wish or I will soon. Thanks guys, sorry again.

Comment: could you please clarify your problem? I think you can access `edgeList` from the function `addEdge` and add a weight to the edge between nodes, Can't you?

Comment: I'll try to simplifiy my problem:
Inside the class of a .cpp file I have a method in which I am trying to access a private variable from a .h file of the same name. The .cpp file includes the .h file, the method has the ClassName::methodName, and the reference has the ClassName::varName, where this var is a private variable of the .h file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply misunderstand the structure here, or maybe I do.

As far as I understand, you are going to put code into the

```
addEdge()
```

method in the

```
class ListGraph
```

This gives you access to the private variable "edgeList".

The abstract class is the "Graph" class, which the "ListGraph" inherits. However, the private variables in ListGraph is available for the ListGraph class.

Your logic is fine, however I think you have misunderstood the "NOTE: THIS CLASS MUST STAY AS IS" as ut says

```
/* Code here */
```

within the addEdge method, I am certain you're allowed to edit it! :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `Graph` is the base class, not `ListGraph`, so I'm not sure if your description is accurate, but as I understand it, you're implementing `ListGraph::addEdge()`.. so you can just access `ListGraph::edgeList`.

Answer (score 0):

The base class `Graph` is actually just specifying what you have to provide when you derive from it - that's why its functions are "pure virtual". The class `ListGraph` is where the data is, and is where you are going to define the function `addEdge`. In that function you will have read/write access to the `edgeList`. Try it, it'll work.